Is the current direction in transmitting and receiving dipole antenna opposite?
I googled for quite a while, but couldn't get a confirmation to this basic question.  So I wonder if someone would help me out here.
Suppose we have 2 dipole antennas, each of length 1 meter.  One acts as the transmitter, and the other is the receiver.  Suppose we apply a 60Hz AC voltage to the transmitting dipole, and place the receiving dipole side-by-side with the transmitter, separated by a short distance, say 1 meter.
Question: Is the direction of the current in the receiving dipole opposite to the current direction in the transmitting dipole?
(I tend to think so, due to the following:  Suppose the 2 antennas are placed vertically.  Initially, as the current in the Tx dipole flows upward, positive charges would accumulate in the upper half of the Tx dipole.  So I suppose the electric field would point largely downward at the Rx dipole, causing the Rx current to flow downward.  Am I mistaken?)

An effective dipole antenna for 60 Hz has to be over 1000 kilometers long. What you propose will just make a  (not very effective) capacitor, unless you build it on a continental scale.

@ThePhoton I understood it's not a typical $\lambda/2$ dipole.  I'm just trying to understand the basic principle, without solving the Maxwell eq's.  Would the question be more answerable if we increase the AC frequency to $1.5\times 10^8$ Hz?

This depends on distance of the dipoles, because the receiving dipole follows the oscillating driving electric field of the emitting dipole (with some small phase shift due to radiation self-interaction of the receiver); direction of that oscillating field changes with distance from the emitter, and switches to the opposite direction after at most one half wavelength.
If the dipoles are much closer together than one half wavelength, so the two dipoles are very near each other, the emitter field acts on the receiver to oscillate in anti-phase, but the two dipoles can be so close together that action of the receiver back on the emitter may be important, and then this mutual interaction may be such (I expect, but did not check the formulae) that dipoles need not oscillate in perfect anti-phase, but there may be additional phase delay due to mutual interaction.
